# JSON_AGG with postgressql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to write a query for grouping JSON in PostgreSQL.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Your desired output is also not clear at all. Please improve your question.

Comment: in that i want group by json_agg value also

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (delay_numeric_code)
       /* your select list */
FROM ...
GROUP BY delay_numeric_code, /* others */;
```

If you care which of the results with the same `delay_numeric_code` you get, you had better add an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: already i need group by  dc.id,dc.category_department, Inside JSON_AGG i want group by delay_numeric_code